# Where does Flask store uploaded files?

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, werkzeug

Where does Flask store uploaded files before the application code has a chance to save the file? Unless I've missed something it doesn't appear to be showing up in the /tmp directory, which is what I'd have expected, and obviously it's not showing up in the directory I've specified in `app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY']`. It's not storing it in memory, is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you check [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads)? It seems pretty clear:

> So how exactly does Flask handle uploads? Well it will store them in the webserver’s memory if the files are reasonable small otherwise in a temporary location (as returned by **`tempfile.gettempdir()`**)